# LaTeX formulas in gnuplot plot legends?

Tags: pdftex, gnuplot

I would like to have my `gnuplot` legends set in LaTeX math mode, because they often are described by a formula. I use `wxMaxima` to generate the plots, but I could switch to using `gnuplot` directly, if that makes things simpler. I am also using `pdflatex`, and would like to stick to that.

Comment: If you use the `tikz` or the `epslatex` terminal in gnuplot and then include the resulting files in a LaTeX document, all the text will be typeset using LaTeX, so you can just use math mode directly. Would that be a feasible workflow?

Comment: Hm, I just tried using the epslatex terminal, but I just get an empty grid, when trying to plot x**2. Got to debug this. But that would be a usable workflow.

Comment: Hm, for some reason the .tex file produced by gnuplot is cut off. the \begingroup is never being closed. No idea why that should be broken...

Comment: You might also want to look at using [tag:pgfplots], which creates the plots directly in the LaTeX documents and can easily use gnuplot as a backend for doing the calculations. This usually leads to much more nicely integrated plots.

Comment: Ah, yes, you need to call `set out <filename.tex>`, do the plotting, and then call `set out` (without a file name) again, to close the file.

Comment: @Jake: thank you a lot! That was exactly the problem!

Comment: @Jake or Arne: How about writing a short tutorial for the rest of us to see and putting it in as an answer.  That would be really useful, I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Concerning Andrew's wish for a short tutorial: Here it is. First, we set up a gnuplot called test.plt:

```
plot [-5:5] [-1.5:1.5] sin(x+pi) title "$\\sin(x+\\pi)$"
```

Then we also set up a small Makefile:

```
.SUFFIXES: .plt .tex .pdf

%.tex: %.plt
gnuplot -e "        set format '$$%g$$' ;       set terminal epslatex standalone color ;        set output '$@'         " $<

%.pdf: %.tex
pdflatex $<

all: test.pdf
```

Running "make all" will produce this plot:

[image: The resulting plot with a LaTeX legend title.]

Note: Backslashes need to be doubled for some reason. I guess they have a special meaning as well in gnuplot.

Comment: Three comments: 1. You need not call `set output`, because Gnuplot will close the output file when it exits; 2. Use `set format '$%g$'` to typeset numbers in mathmode (needed for minus sign); 3. Do you really need to crop the file? I have never used it.

Comment: 1. Alright. It was necessary when I was trying it interactively.
2. Can you elaborate? I tried typesetting a "$-2$" and it worked just fine, I think.
3. Without cropping, I get an A4 page. However, I'd like a tightly fitting PDF that I can use wherever I want. :)

Comment: Plot `sin(x)` from -5 to 5 with and without the alternate format and look at the x axis labels. This is the same as when you type `$-1$`, not `-1` to get minus one in TeX.

Comment: If you don't plan to include the plot in a document and want to typeset it separately, consider using the `standalone` option of the `epslatex` terminal. It will give the correct size without any cropping.

Comment: Good hint! I will try that option PS: which texlive package contains the minimal documentclass? My installation does not have it, yet...

Comment: andrey: yes, I was mistaken, it's fixed now. I also changed the plot, and am using a Makefile now to re-generate my plots. This is finally the solution I was looking for. All I need now is color in my plots, but I guess I will manage.

Comment: Naturally there is another `epslatex` terminal option for color plots. I suggest to read the corresponding entry in the Gnuplot manual.

Comment: @Arne let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1188/discussion-between-andrey-vihrov-and-arne)

Comment: You can use single quotes for the title, then you don't need the double backslashes...